# Cumulative sum in query from more than one tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to list woocommerce orders ordered with particular coupon and I want to add column with cumulative sum. I have tried `SUM(_order_total) OVER(ORDER BY po.ID)` but it does not work.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(po.post_date, '%Y-%m-%d ') as Order_date,
       po.ID AS Order_Number,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_order_total' AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS Total
FROM `wpl9_posts` AS pc
INNER JOIN `wpl9_postmeta` AS pmc ON  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id`
INNER JOIN `wpl9_woocommerce_order_items` AS woi ON pc.post_title = woi.order_item_name
    AND woi.order_item_type = 'coupon'
INNER JOIN `wpl9_posts` AS po ON woi.order_id = po.ID
    AND po.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND po.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-refunded') -- Added needed order status over here.
INNER JOIN `wpl9_postmeta` AS pmo ON po.ID = pmo.post_id
WHERE pc.post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND
      pc.post_title = 'partner001' AND
GROUP BY po.ID
ORDER BY pc.ID DESC
```

Comment: Please give example input, expected output, and provide the error message.

Comment: formatted code; improved wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
select q.*,
       (@sum := @sum + total) as running_sum
from (<your query here>) q cross join
     (select @sum := 0) params;
```